# Using accelerometer data to determine if something strikes the device

Tags: accelerometer, sensors, vibration

I need some help with this problem.  I want to detect when an object hits a device (which has an accelerometer built in) that's resting on a table.  The hit/strike, say by a ball, causes a fast spike in the Z values and if the hit is in the center, very little y or x movement occurs.  The problem I am facing is how to differentiate between a normal ball strike, and a bump of the table or a even a placing of a glass on the table which causes a vibration.  Intuitively I think the ball strike will be faster and a different wave length that a table side bump or placing a object down hard on the table.

I can detect when a strike hits the edge of the device , large x and y values occur with some z, but the key is how to I detect a good hit, i.e. as close to the center as possible and not record a false positive by actions/vibrations that are not hitting the device at all?

Pete

Comment: I imagine this has to be done empirically.  Record the spike that occurs when you do each of those motion and use those results to decide on a threshold. ;)

Comment: I think this calls for some testing!

Comment: oh I've done testing, lots of it.  I was thinking perhaps mapping the x y z values to a cubic function and use statistics to measure the confidence interval of the good hit, i.e. the curve will not be a normal distribution but the "hump" will be skewed to the left of the norm.  I'm a bit rusty on my stats so was thinking perhaps someone out there can help me determine what the "function" formula is and I'd try that.